# Image.FromStream is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, xampp

So I use this code to display my data in a `DataGridView`:

```
Sub display_Infodata()
    DGUSERS.Rows.Clear()
    Dim sql As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_info", con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    DGUSERS.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DGUSERS.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DGUSERS.RowTemplate.Height = 40
    sql.Fill(ds, 0)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim xx As Integer = DGUSERS.Rows.Add
        Dim uid As String = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
        Dim sqls As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_other where userid='" & uid & "'", con)
        Dim dss As New DataSet

        sqls.Fill(dss, 0)
        With DGUSERS.Rows(xx)
            If dss.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                .Cells(0).Value = uid
                .Cells(1).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2).ToString
                .Cells(2).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3).ToString
                .Cells(3).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4).ToString
                .Cells(4).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5).ToString
                .Cells(5).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(6).ToString
                .Cells(6).Value = dss.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
                .Cells(7).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
                .Cells(8).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(8).ToString
                .Cells(9).Value = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Image")
                .Cells(10).Value = dss.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
                .Cells(11).Value = dss.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3).ToString
            Else

            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

It displays and works, but my problem is that when I try to display the data in the `DataGridView` of another form it shows the following error:

[image: Error screenshot]

This is what I use:

```
Try
    With View_Info
        Dim index As Integer
        Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
        selectedRow = DGUSERS.Rows(index)

        .UserID.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("UserID").Value
        .UserType.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("UserType").Value
        .Fname.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Firstname").Value
        .Mname.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Middlename").Value
        .Lname.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Lastname").Value
        .Contact.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Contact").Value
        .Standing.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Standing").Value
        .Guardian.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Guardian").Value
        .ContactG.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("GuardianContact").Value
        .DPCreated.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("DateCreated").Value
        .DPValidity.Text = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Validity").Value

        Dim img As Byte()
        img = DGUSERS.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Image").Value
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)

        .UploadImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        .Show()
        .Focus()

    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & " Please select a corresponding records.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
End Try
```

Any help please?

Comment: my problem is it says : 'fromstream' is not a member of system.windows.datagridviewimagecolumn

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tip: formatting code is done by indenting it with four spaces. The backticks ( \` ) are just for inline escaping and not whole code blocks. For instance, they're used when you're talking about code objects such as `Image.FromStream` or a `DataGridView`.

Comment: See the [**markdown help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see the full picture, but the problem is most likely that you have created a `DataGridViewImageColumn` which you've chosen to call `Image`.

The compiler will always choose local variables, properties or classes over library/pre-imported namespace objects with the same name. Thus, your column by the name `Image` will be used rather than `System.Drawing.Image` because the former is "more local".

Try specifying the namespace as well and it should work:

```
.UploadImage.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried using   Dim pCell As New DataGridViewImageCell

   pCell = Me.DGUSERS.Item("Picture", e.RowIndex) .UploadImage.Image = byteArrayToImage(pCell.Value) and it works :) my problem now is the datetime

Comment: @KirsthyLizo : What is the problem with the DateTime, and on what line is it?

Comment: I'm getting this error: the string was not recognized as a valid datetime. there is an unknown word starting at index 0. You see, I'm calling another winform to display my data from the datagridview

Comment: @KirsthyLizo : You better ask a new question about that and show the exact line where it happens and also the string you're trying to get converted. Use the [**Autos/Locals windows**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx) of the debugger to inspect variables when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @KirsthyLizo : No problem, glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

So what I did to solve this is by:

```
Dim pCell As New DataGridViewImageCell
pCell = Me.DGUSERS.Item("Picture", e.RowIndex)

.UploadImage.Image = byteArrayToImage(pCell.Value)
```

and using this function:

```
Private Function byteArrayToImage(ByVal byt As Byte()) As Image

    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim drwimg As Image = Nothing

    Try
        ms.Write(byt, 0, byt.Length)
        drwimg = New Bitmap(ms)
    Finally
        ms.Close()
    End Try

    Return drwimg

End Function
```